# Codesigning error in Archive build in Xcode, Watch Kit extension added the bundle identifier issue

Tags: xcode, code-signing

```
CopySwiftLibs /Users/sivakumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/High_Messaging-cfpetwgbaeibqfbpvkblrzcqtjdk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/High\ Messaging/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/watchos/High\ Message\ Extension.appex (in target: High Message Extension)
    cd /Users/sivakumar/Desktop/HMapr042018
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
    export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    export SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchOS5.2.sdk
    builtin-swiftStdLibTool --copy --verbose --sign 1E76CDEED922E7056A4F2302E48C248A4C0D93CF --scan-executable /Users/sivakumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/High_Messaging-cfpetwgbaeibqfbpvkblrzcqtjdk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/High\ Messaging/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/watchos/High\ Message\ Extension.appex/High\ Message\ Extension --scan-folder /Users/sivakumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/High_Messaging-cfpetwgbaeibqfbpvkblrzcqtjdk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/High\ Messaging/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/watchos/High\ Message\ Extension.appex/Frameworks --scan-folder /Users/sivakumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/High_Messaging-cfpetwgbaeibqfbpvkblrzcqtjdk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/High\ Messaging/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/watchos/High\ Message\ Extension.appex/PlugIns --platform watchos --toolchain /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain --destination /Users/sivakumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/High_Messaging-cfpetwgbaeibqfbpvkblrzcqtjdk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/High\ Messaging/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/watchos/High\ Message\ Extension.appex/Frameworks --unsigned-destination /Users/sivakumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/High_Messaging-cfpetwgbaeibqfbpvkblrzcqtjdk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/High\ Messaging/BuildProductsPath/SwiftSupport --emit-dependency-info /Users/sivakumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/High_Messaging-cfpetwgbaeibqfbpvkblrzcqtjdk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/High\ Messaging/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/High\ Messaging.build/Release-watchos/High\ Message\ Extension.build/SwiftStdLibToolInputDependencies.dep

Requested Swift ABI version based on scanned binaries: unstable(7)
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/watchos/libswiftSceneKit.dylib to /Users/sivakumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/High_Messaging-cfpetwgbaeibqfbpvkblrzcqtjdk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/High Messaging/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/watchos/High Message Extension.appex/Frameworks/libswiftSceneKit.dylib
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/watchos/libswiftMapKit.dylib to /Users/sivakumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/High_Messaging-cfpetwgbaeibqfbpvkblrzcqtjdk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/High Messaging/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/watchos/High Message Extension.appex/Frameworks/libswiftMapKit.dylib
... lots more copying ...
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/watchos/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib to /Users/sivakumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/High_Messaging-cfpetwgbaeibqfbpvkblrzcqtjdk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/High Messaging/BuildProductsPath/SwiftSupport/watchos/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
Copying /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/watchos/libswiftFoundation.dylib to /Users/sivakumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/High_Messaging-cfpetwgbaeibqfbpvkblrzcqtjdk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/High Messaging/BuildProductsPath/SwiftSupport/watchos/libswiftFoundation.dylib
Probing signature of /Users/sivakumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/High_Messaging-cfpetwgbaeibqfbpvkblrzcqtjdk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/High Messaging/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/watchos/High Message Extension.appex/Frameworks/libswiftSceneKit.dylib
/usr/bin/codesign -r- --display /Users/sivakumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/High_Messaging-cfpetwgbaeibqfbpvkblrzcqtjdk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/High Messaging/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/watchos/High Message Extension.appex/Frameworks/libswiftSceneKit.dylib
Codesigning /Users/sivakumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/High_Messaging-cfpetwgbaeibqfbpvkblrzcqtjdk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/High Messaging/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/watchos/High Message Extension.appex/Frameworks/libswiftSceneKit.dylib
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 1E76CDEED922E7056A4F2302E48C248A4C0D93CF --verbose /Users/sivakumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/High_Messaging-cfpetwgbaeibqfbpvkblrzcqtjdk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/High Messaging/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/watchos/High Message Extension.appex/Frameworks/libswiftSceneKit.dylib
/Users/sivakumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/High_Messaging-cfpetwgbaeibqfbpvkblrzcqtjdk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/High Messaging/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/watchos/High Message Extension.appex/Frameworks/libswiftSceneKit.dylib: replacing existing signature
/Users/sivakumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/High_Messaging-cfpetwgbaeibqfbpvkblrzcqtjdk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/High Messaging/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/watchos/High Message Extension.appex/Frameworks/libswiftSceneKit.dylib: errSecInternalComponent

error: Failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please review [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Codesigning+error%3A+Failed+with+exit+code+1)

Comment: check your swift libraries swift version and your app swift version.